# Output objects from Ajax to Twig

Tags: jquery, ajax, twig, symfony

In Symfony 3 I have a sort and I'm using ajax to get the objects from backend.

This is in controller:

```
if($request->getMethod() === 'POST' && isset($_POST['sort'])) {
  if($_POST['sort'] === 'title_up') {
     $products = $em->createQuery("SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Product a ORDER BY a.title ASC")->getArrayResult();
... etc.
  }
}

return new JsonResponse($products);
```

I get the object in frontend:

```
$('#form_select').on('change', function()  {
  var path = "{{ '/' }}";
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
  console.log(path);
  var valueSelected = this.value;
  if($.trim(valueSelected) != '')
   {
   /*$('#items').text(data);*/
   $.post(path, {sort : valueSelected}, function(data) {
     console.log('dump', data[0].title);
     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       $('#items').append(data[i].title)
       }
     })
   }
});
```

The question is: Is there a better way to render the objects than using a loop and adding data[i].description, data[i].title ... etc?

Im using twig and it would be great if somehow I can pass the variable data to twig to create the view I need. (Just like i render any other variable passed from controller to twig)

Comment: use a template engine if you don't like the append, twig is php you are currently working with js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twig is template engine for PHP, so it's server-side. It means you can't pass something from your frontend (JS) to Twig directly.

But you still can render twig template in your controller and return in in ajax call and paste where you want in your frondend

```
return new JsonResponse([
    'html' => $this->renderView('your_twig_file.html.twig', ['products' => $products])
]
);
```

Comment: This should get more love.